# How do we know which case we should use relative pronoun in?

Tags: grammatical-case, relative-pronoun

In [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69748/does-the-preposition-control-the-case-or-does-the-verb), I understood that verbs determine the case of nouns and prepositions determine case of prepositional objects. And in [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70098/understanding-relation-between-different-versions-of-relative-pronouns), the three group of relative pronoun is discussed.

My question is, how do we figure out what is the case of a relative pronoun when writing a German sentence? I can't see how can one extrapolate the idea in the first post to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relative pronoun takes the case depending on the role it has in the relative sentence. This can be seen when you transform the relative sentence in a full sentence:

Nominative:

1. Ein Satz, *der* stimmt. → *Der Satz* stimmt.

Genitive:

2. Ein Satz, *dessen* Anfang ich vergessen habe. → Ich habe den Anfang *des Satzes* vergessen.

Dative:

3. Ein Satz, *dem* ich glaube. → Ich glaube *dem Satz.*

Accusative:

3. Ein Satz, *den* ich schreibe. → Ich schreibe *den Satz.*

Comment: So are all usages of relative pronommen actually a contraction of a longer sentence

Comment: I see your second example as accusative.

Comment: @Buraian: Relative sentences are not contractions, but they can be transformed into full sentences. See [relative clause - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause) for more information.

Comment: @CarstenS: The relative pronoun «dessen» and the corresponding phrase «des Satzes» are genitives. The main use of the genitive is for possessive attributes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I wanted an example in which "dessen" is an object, but there is really no reason for that because, as you say, that is not the main use of the genitive.